# How replace value element in array?

Tags: php, arrays

Code:

```
$record=array('test','test1','test2');

$product = $record[0];


$arr = array(
  array( "test", "1", "test5" ),
  array( "test5", "3", "test5" )
);

foreach ($arr as $keys => $elms) {

  if($product==$elms[0]){

    // here need to increase the value of the $elms[1] on one;
    // for ex. if $product==$elms[0] in result need get next array:
    // $arr = array(
    //   array( "test", "2", "test5" ),
    //   array( "test5", "3", "test5" )
    // );
  }  
}
```

Tell me please how increase the value ?

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand what you want. Could you provide a better explanation of what you want to achieve?

Comment: `$elms[1]++` maybe? It is hard to understand what you want.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn yes, i want a sleep and stuped(

Comment: Dont understand thumbs down, all he want explained in remark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To modify elements of array you iterate over, you need to use `&` to indicate you want reference to be returned by `foreach`, not **copy** of the element. Also, I'd recommend replacing `"1"` and `"3"` with `1` and `3` respectively. For a good habit.

```
<?php
$record=array('test','test1','test2');

$product = $record[0];

$arr = array(
  array( "test", "1", "test5" ),
  array( "test5", "3", "test5" )
);

foreach ($arr as $keys => &$elms) {   // here, the & is the key...
  if($product==$elms[0]){
   $elms[1]++;
  }
}

print_r($arr);
```